# Solmate ERC20 SafeTransfer

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transfer, mint

Implemented a ERC20Mintable but the safeTransfer in the safeTrans function reverts `TRANSFER_FAILED`.

Wondering what I did wrong here. Thanks.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "solmate/src/tokens/ERC20.sol";
import "solmate/src/utils/SafeTransferLib.sol";


contract ERC20Mintable is ERC20 {
  
  using SafeTransferLib for ERC20;


  constructor (string memory name, string memory code, uint8 decimal) 
    ERC20(name, code, decimal) 
  {

  }

  function mint(address to, uint amount) public {
    _mint(to, amount);
  }

  function safeTrans(address to, uint amount) public {

    ERC20(this).safeApprove(to, amount);

    ERC20(this).safeTransfer(to, amount);

  }

}
```

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { TASK_COMPILE_SOLIDITY_HANDLE_COMPILATION_JOBS_FAILURES } = require("hardhat/builtin-tasks/task-names");

describe('ERC20Mntable', function() {

  describe('test safetransfer', () => {
    it('safetransfer', async () => {
      const token0 = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC20Mintable");
      contract0 = await token0.deploy('token0', 'TOK0', 18);
  
      const token1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC20Mintable");
      contract1 = await token1.deploy('token1', 'TOK1', 18);

      [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();

      await contract0.connect(owner).mint(owner.getAddress(), 1000)    
      await contract0.connect(addr1).mint(addr1.getAddress(), 1000)
  
      await contract1.connect(owner).mint(owner.getAddress(), 1000)
      await contract1.connect(addr1).mint(addr1.getAddress(), 1000)

      await contract0.connect(owner).safeTrans(addr1.getAddress(), 500)

    })
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your function `safeTrans()` needs to be changed a little.

1. Unfortunately, you cannot give approval here using `safeApprove()`, because using this library, the token contract becomes the `msg.sender` and the approval is not perfectly given. Also, you need to give approval to the contract address, not the `to` address.
2. I am guessing you need to transfer the tokens from 1 user's wallet to the 2nd using contract's function? In this case, you need to use `safeTranferFrom()`. The final code will be something like:

   ```
   function safeTrans(address to, uint amount) public {
       approve(address(this), amount);
       ERC20(this).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);
   }
   ```

Comment: Great thanks. I am curious why safeApprove doesn't work, i.e.ERC20(this).safeApprove(address(this), amount);

Comment: According to me, the reason for it not working was `ERC20(this)` instance you were attaching to `safeApprove()`. When you do that, the attached instance becomes the target contract, and thus the calling contract becomes the `msg.sender`. Here, both the contracts were in fact your own contract. Thus, approval was given from your contract itself, instead of from your actual `msg.sender` address. Expected allowance was never provided.